# Htaccess: RewriteCond does not work with multiple conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need when user to send this Url format:

```
localhost/application/form.php
```

To redirect and pass dinamically the 'form.php' as parameter for:

```
localhost/application/index.php/site/integration/form.php
```

For anothers urls format to redirect to:

```
localhost/application/index.php
```

I heave this code, but does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*.php
RewriteRule .*.php index.php/site/integracao - [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php - [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this .htaccess located inside `application/` folder?

Comment: yes the .htacess is in application/folder

Comment: if you to know another way do that please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `application/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[\w-]+\.php$ index.php/site/integration/$0 [L,NC]
```